# how to use be and become

Tags: word-choice, tense

> One day, I'll be a rich person. 
>    One day, I'll become a rich person

And,

> I've been a rich person. 
>   I've become a rich  person

Can I use 'become' instead of 'be' there or any other verbs similar to Become?

Answer (score 2):

First two sentences can be used interchangeably with 'become' version seeming a bit more definite.

In the third and fourth sentence the difference is:

> I've been a rich person

suggests that until now or recently you have been rich. While

> I've become a rich person

suggests that 'now' you are definitely rich regardless of any uncertainties.

Answer (score 1):

Both means that **on that day** you are 'X'. But then....the subtle difference is very interesting.

> One day, I'll become a doctor

talks about the course of action. That said, you are *under the process* of becoming a doctor. To clear this point, **think that** a *medical student* speaks that sentence when he's in some medical college, pursuing a course of MBBS degree.

On the other hand,

> One day, I'll be a doctor

talks about someone's dream to become a doctor. Not necessarily the person uttering this sentence should be in the middle of any course as in the first example.

All in all, when you use *become..* it involves the current process/efforts to become that and when you opt for *be...* it denotes that one day, you'll be 'that'.

Furthermore, `I've been a rich person`talks about *at one point of time* in your life, you were rich. And `I have become a rich person` reflects your *current status* of being rich.